# how to reach JButton from main function

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I created a window named "okno", where I have JButton named "tlcOdejit" and I wanna disable that button when I read some text from input. But when I type

```
okno.tlcOdejit.setEnabled(false);
```

compiler is telling me "cannot find symbol -> tlcOdejit". 
I am able to use function for JTextArea like

```
okno.textArea1.append(line);
```

for type a line into my textArea, but I am not able to reach this way the button. Could you tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of okno, and does it have a tlcOdejit field? (The Java language doesn't know about windows and buttons, only classes, fields, objects, etc)

Comment: Please add the code where you are getting this error.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE

Comment: Its like I have class Client extends JFrame and its initialized in main function as Client okno = new Client(). The tlcOdejit is included in JPanel named "hlavni".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is tlcOdejit public? If not, that could be the problem.

Comment: yea... I am such an idiot :D thanks